# Drush pm-update needs a module?

Tags: drush

When trying to run `Drush pm-update' in a site i get the error

```
Command pm-update needs the following modules installed/enabled to run: update.                              [error]
The drush command 'pm-update' could not be executed.
```

Oddly this command was recently working (on other sites in the same core installation), and further more I have no idea where to find or what is this 'update' module. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The [Update manager](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/update) is a core module, you just need to `drush en update`  or do it through the interface

Comment: You can also try `drush up`, it works for me

Comment: ('drush up' is just short for 'drush pm-update').

Comment: From drush version 7.1.0 on you don't need to enable the update module anymore as it calls https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_rebuild_module_data/7

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's in `<drupal_root>/modules/update`. If not, it means you damaged your core.

Try `drush en update` - it should re-enable it for you. After performing updates you are allowed to disable it again.